# Autocomplete disable styling? (Picture attached)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui + react. I am building a simple form and everything is working fine except I have a small UI that Im not sure how to fix. Whenever I use the browser auto-complete, the input field remains highlighted. I've been digging through the CSS in the chrome dev tools and cannot find what is setting this.

This happens in all textfields right now.
Still happens when I remove custom styling from the component.

Hard to put into words so here are some screenshots:

Before:
[image: Before]

After:

[image]

It then remains highlighted after I click away and select something else. However, if I type in a password this highlighting does not take place.

Component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    border: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    width: '75%',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
})

const LoginForm = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    <TextField
          name='password'
          type='password'
          value={formik.values.password}
          className={classes.border}
          variant='outlined'
          label='Password'
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
          helperText={formik.touched.password ? formik.errors.password : ''}
        />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my theme.js seemed to fix the issue for me:

```
const theme = {
    overrides: {
        MuiOutlinedInput: {
          input: {
            '&:-webkit-autofill': {
              WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 100px #303030 inset',
              WebkitTextFillColor: '#fff',
        },
      },
    },
    }
}
```